# module is not in the npm registry

Tags: node.js, npm, nightmare

I want to download file using nightmare js.

I tried to use this:
https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-inline-download

I tried to run

```
npm install --save nightmare-inline-download
```

But git this:

```
`npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/nightma
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'nightmare-inline-dowload' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

`

What do I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You typed in *dowload* instead of **download**, it's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

try this command to download this lib

```
npm i nightmare-inline-download --save
```